# Google Analytics Realtime report suddenly shows very few views by page title, even though many users are present

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

Here's what this looks like in my dashboard.

[image]

This never used to happen, but now it's my norm. This behavior coincided around the same time I set up google tag manager and started promoting my content with paid Reddit and Google ads. Why does this occur?

Comment: Firstly double check your tag to be implemented correctly in all the pages. Then check your property in GA4 to be set correctly.

Comment: What @RezaAtaei said. Add screenshots showing your debugging. Use GTM preview. Show the tag, also show the content of your pageviews. It's possible that the titles aren't being set for certain pages if, say, they have no titles. Or if you override the title dimension in GTM, which is unlikely though.

Comment: I fixed this. It turns out, I had two google tag manager scripts in my code. After I removed the redundant one, my page views began showing again. (I the redundant script tag may have also been improperly set up.)